# Quickly Undo Accidental Event Generation

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Double-clicking on a control in Visual Studio is a very intuitive way to generate the default event handler.  However, I often accidentally double click on a control therefore creating an event handler that I do not need.

Usually, I do one of the following to remove the blank, unused, event handler.

Current methods

1. **Undo** (Ctrl+Z): Also performs undo on all unsaved form changes.
2. **Delete Method, Delete Handler**: Delete the new method.  Delete the event handler in event properties for the control.
3. **Delete Method, Recompile, Select Error, Delete EventHandler in Designer Code**: Quicker if code is ready to compile.

Does anyone have an easier way to undo an accidental control event generation?

Comment: You forgot about the swearing. You're supposed to start swearing when this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just delete the handler in the event properties as in point 2.
This should completely remove the event.

Comment: It works!  When removing the handler (from the Properties window), the Designer also removes the method, as long as the method is blank and no longer referenced.

Comment: Quickest so far.  I'll consider later answers if quicker.

Answer (score 1):

> How to undo an accidental control event generation?

Save often, check in often. When making many tiny changes to something, like a form or database diagram, it helps to have either fast or local version control, so you can perform pretty fine-grained rollbacks in the case you mess something up.

Visual Studio's Undo will only take you back so many steps if the designer allows it, while a commit / shelve after each action (adding a control or database table, changing certain properties) creates a fixed point in time to which you can return.